# Where can I find jar files for com.experitest.client

Tags: seetest

I am new to seeTest and just try a demo of record and playback feature. I copied the code but don't know from where can I find com.experitest.client

Answer (score 1):

You can add https://cloud.experitest.com/repo/ to your repositories, and pull the jar from there.
for example, you are using Gradle:
repositories {

```
maven {
    url "https://cloud.experitest.com/repo/"
}
```

...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile group: 'com.experitest', name: 'seetest-client', version: '+'
    ...
}

You can find more information [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+Maven+Repository+-+Maven+and+Gradle+Syntax)